# Should Product Backlog Items and Tasks ever be in different Iteration Paths?

Tags: tfs, scrum, workitem, tfs-workitem

Using the Scrum 2.1 process template, I noticed that the Sprint Backlog query in TFS returns a list of Product Backlog Items and Tasks for the sprint, but the list looked pretty sparse as I reviewed it. After poking around in the query definition for a little bit, I realized that it was matching first on child links, and filtering children based on the iteration. This mattered because several tasks hadn't been assigned an iteration and were thus sitting in the backlog.

This got me thinking, though--since the primary focus in the sprint is on the Product Backlog Item, and a PBI is meant to be started and finished during a single sprint, then why would it ever make sense for the Tasks to be in a different iteration? Is there a reason? As well, would there be a reason for the Sprint Backlog query to be structured this way?

Answer (score 4):

It depends how your're using TFS to plan your sprints. If your intention is to use the full extent of the [TFS 2012 Agile Planning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189203.aspx) features you need to maintain the work items iterations. The Scrum board feature isn't affected by the Sprint Backlog query (or any other queries for that matter), it is controlled by the [scheduling and areas settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500418.aspx) in the Team's administration (available in the team's Home):

[image: Configure schedule and iterations...]

The iteration depends on the size of the PBI: If a PBI, including all its child tasks can fit in a single sprint, iteration should be set to the sprint (e.g.: `\Release 1\Sprint 4\`).

If the PBI is big enough to span across multiple sprints to complete, keep its iteration on the release level (e.g.: `\Release 1\`) and its child tasks to the sprint level.

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the end of a Sprint and 3/4 PBI's have been completed implemented and accepted while the final PBI has 2/3 tasks completely implemented you have some difficult decisions to make. Do you:

a) attempt to rip out the code of that last PBI?

b) call the entire Sprint a failure and start over?

c) move the unfinished child task to the next Sprint?

This is in support of option (c). Probably not what Scrum.org would recommend, but that is the scenario it is supporting.

Comment: Our intent is to keep in-process PBIs low, and to execute them in branches, so that essentially we get a) for free when a PBI doesn't finish on time. The PBI & remaining tasks are kicked back to the backlog to be rescheduled, and the remaining work is then re-estimated. So essentially, yeah; kind of a combination of A and C, except that the PBI comes with it, so they're still both in the same sprint.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a workable feature at the end of the sprint, the remaining work should be broken out into a new product backlog item and the tasks associated with the new PBI.

If you don't do this you end up managing a collection of partially completed PBI which is painful to keep track of and will throw off your reports.

I'm not sure how you would effectively groom your backlog and do sprint planning without splitting the remaining work into a new PBI.

If you run into this situation often, consider decomposing your PBI into smaller blocks of work.  Remember that an ideal PBI size is in the 3-5 days (3 Story Points on my scale) or less range by the time you get to the point of committing the PBI to a sprint.

Here is a good blog describing size: http://www.agileforall.com/2009/12/agile-antipattern-taking-on-large-stories/

Thread that discusses size and includes a reference to 3-5 days: [When to create PBI's from a feature request and where to draw the line into splitting them up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753059/when-to-create-pbis-from-a-feature-request-and-where-to-draw-the-line-into-spli)

Comment: In the case that the PBI is somehow both deliverable and incomplete, then yeah I can see this working; however we're pretty strict about only promoting work that satisfies all the acceptance criteria, so this hasn't actually happened for us. When we don't manage to finish, we don't promote the incomplete work, and instead re-estimate the PBI based on the remaining work, which helps to hone our velocity measurements because A) we got no credit for the work from the previous sprint, and B) we'll allocate effort for it in the next sprint according to the work we've still yet to do.

Comment: Also can you source a recommendation on PBIs being 3 points or fewer? That's something we haven't been using; our team uses higher numbers typically, and while probably works out (all the PBIs are estimated by the same people using the same decision-making process), it'd probably be good to get more standardized in case we add on other people with different experience.

Comment: I should have used ideal days instead of Story Points in my answer.  You bring up a good point that a story point scale is specific to the group making the estimates.  I went back and modified my answer accordingly.  One of the best ways i've used to establish a durable scale is to come up with an example story that is equivalent to that 3-5 day time frame and base your scale on that.  It makes it easy to   recant the story in the heat of planning and compare it to the item you estimating for.